# How to give Image from another thread?

Tags: swift, multithreading

I have a code for getting user pic:

```
if let photoURL = message[Constants.MessageFields.photoURL], let URL = URL(string: photoURL),
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: URL) {
    cell.userPic.image = UIImage(data: data)
}
```

When I'm using it, tableView lagging at scrolling.

Please help me to put this code in another thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a good sample provided by Apple, that you can adapt for your needs:

[Prefetching collection view data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasourceprefetching/prefetching_collection_view_data)

Basic idea is to create `AsyncFetcher` for your images and put image creation code to separate operation.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Cell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? Cell else {
        fatalError("Expected `\(Cell.self)` type for reuseIdentifier \(Cell.reuseIdentifier). Check the configuration in Main.storyboard.")
    }

    let model = models[indexPath.row]
    let id = model.id
    cell.representedId = id

    // Check if the `asyncFetcher` has already fetched data for the specified identifier.
    if let fetchedData = asyncFetcher.fetchedData(for: id) {
        // The data has already been fetched and cached; use it to configure the cell.
        cell.configure(with: fetchedData)
    } else {
        // There is no data available; clear the cell until we've fetched data.
        cell.configure(with: nil)

        // Ask the `asyncFetcher` to fetch data for the specified identifier.
        asyncFetcher.fetchAsync(id) { fetchedData in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                /*
                 The `asyncFetcher` has fetched data for the identifier. Before
                 updating the cell, check if it has been recycled by the
                 collection view to represent other data.
                 */
                guard cell.representedId == id else { return }

                // Configure the cell with the fetched image.
                cell.configure(with: fetchedData)
            }
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

But in your case you should use [Table View prefetching](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasourceprefetching)

I can confirm that this approach works and (when done right) results smooth scrolling and good UX